# How do I take an input parameter of a string and turn that into the name of an integer list?

Tags: java

I am writing a basic program that asks the user for the length of a data set, and then lets them manually fill it in in order. I am writing the code so the only input parameter is a string representing what they want to name the array they are creating, but I'm having trouble converting the input string into a variable I can use to name the array.

```
public static void createArray(String n)
{
    int[] a = new int[(int)myFunctions.getValue("How long do you want your integer array?")];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int)myFunctions.getValue("Enter term " + i + " of your integer array");
    }
}
```

Right now I am using 'a' as a placeholder name, but ideally I'd lake variable 'a' to be what the input string 'n' was. Would I have to parse the string to be an integer array?

(note, myFunctions.getValue() just asks the user for an integer input)

Comment: You could have a map<string, integer[]> where the key is the array name

Comment: You can't have dynamic variable names. You could create a Map<String, int[]> where your "variable name" would be a key and store them in there.

Comment: If your string n is space separated integers, you could try `String temp[] = n.split(" ");` Now iterate over temp array and convert it to integer using `Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want to consider using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for something like this. You can take the names as the Key and then assign the integers as the Value. Then you can more easily work with the data how you want, I think.